# Angular 6 - Multiple select change text involuntarily

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular6

I have created a multiple select using `*ngFor` with a list. I have the possibility to create new selects dynamically with a button but now there is a problem with the consistency of the selects.

```
<div *ngFor="let marketSelected of marketTypeListSelected; let i = index">
    <select class="form-control" (change)="onChange($event.target.value, i)"  required>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Choose a market available</option>
      <option *ngFor="let market of marketTypeListAvailable" [value]="market.name + '@'+ market.marketType" [selected]="market.name == marketSelected.name && market.marketType == marketSelected.marketType">{{market.name}} - {{market.marketType}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

If I put the same option in two selects and I change the top one the other change of text but the value assigned to it still correct.

This happens only with two selects and is not necessary be the next one. It can be between the first one and the third one or the second and the forth.

**Example**

[Basis example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hb9Qd.png)

[Example changed the first select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqnVi.png)

[Console output during the change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScXBI.png)

change the value of the first select

**Note**
I don't use `ngModel` because I get the data from other list and `ngModel` changed the attributes of that list.

**Demo**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/bug-angular-select

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why that problem happens but I have fixed the problem using another way to implement the select.

I have created an auxiliary list with the names of the previous list.

```
auxMarketTyleListSelected: string[] = [] ;
ngOnInit(){
    for(let ms of this.marketTypeListSelected){
       this.auxMarketTyleListSelected.push(ms.name + '|' + ms.marketType);
    }
}
```

After that, I have changed the frontend to implement the new select

```
 <div *ngFor="let marketSelected of auxMarketTyleListSelected; let i = index">
    <select (change)="onChange($event.target.value, i)"  required>
      <option value="" disabled selected>- Select a market from get selections -</option>
      <option *ngFor="let market of marketTypeListAvailable"
              [value]="market.name + '|'+ market.marketType"
              [selected]="market.name == marketSelected.split('|')[0] && market.marketType ==marketSelected.split('|')[1]">
        {{market.name}} | {{market.marketType}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Here, the [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bug-select-solved) with the solution to my problem.